# How to serialize the return value of a method in a model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I have a Django app that uses Django REST Framework and Django-allauth. Now, I'm trying to retrieve the avatar URL that's present in the social account. However, I'm having trouble forming the serializer.

For background info, the `allauth`'s `SocialAccount` is related to the user model via a foreign key:

```
class SocialAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(allauth.app_settings.USER_MODEL)


    # the method I'm interested of
    def get_avatar_url(self):
        ...
```

Now, here's the serializer I currently have:

```
class ProfileInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

In the end, I'd like to have an extra field `avatar_url` which takes the result of the method call in the `SocialAccount` model. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution using a `SerializerMethodField`:

```
class ProfileInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_avatar_url(obj, self):
        return obj.socialaccount_set.first().get_avatar_id()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar_url')
```

Comment: This worked for me only when changing `return obj.socialaccount_set...` to `return self.socialaccount_set...` Thanks!